# Why am I getting a straight line for exponential decay curve best-fit?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, exponential, lmfit

[image]

I am trying to fit a curve of a double exponential decay function in Python. The code I have used is as follows. Why am I getting a straight line for the fit?

```
xData = np.array(xData) 
yData = np.array(yData)
def double_exp(x, a1, t1, a2, t2):
    return a1*np.exp(-x/t1) + a2*np.exp(-(x-0.1) / t2)
mod=Model(double_exp)

result=mod.fit(yData,x=xData,a1=0.7,t1=0.5,a2=0.3,t2=10)
result.plot()
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Fluoresence Lifetime')
```

My sample data values for the lists xData and yData is

```
[![xData is \[2.50783699e-09 5.01567398e-09 7.52351097e-09 1.00313480e-08
 1.25391849e-08 1.50470219e-08 1.75548589e-08 2.00626959e-08
 2.25705329e-08... etc\]
yData is \[ 1025.  1032.  1101.  1138.  1205.  1086.  1692. 13515. 59434. 82067.64293. 52266. 43993. 35335. 30066. 29989. 33773. 30521. 26468. 26338.27233. 26276. 24109....etc\]][1]][1]
```

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce what you did because the data joint to the question is not consistent and incomplete. So one cannot look for the cause of trouble.

Comment: Could you please explain? I'm unable to follow @JJacquelin

Comment: They are 9 numbers in your xData. They are 23 numbers in your yData. So it is not consistant. They are much more points on your graph than in the Data. Without your whole Data one cannot reproduce exactly your calculus. One cannot observe the straight line that you get. So one cannot find the cause of the trouble.

Comment: @JJacquelin  no actually they are of same size..I just wanted to show an example of what my list data look like

Comment: Can you understand that showing a graph and a partial data is not enough. If you don't   give a full numerical example I will not answer to the question.

Comment: A few observations. 1) Always try to scale your data to 1. Here results can be scaled back easily later. 2) The data around (0, 0) does not go well with your model (start-up artifact in the measurement?) and probably should be removed. 3) The manual shift ( x - 0.1) is way outside the data range as this is of order 1e-7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting a straight line because your initial values are not close enough to be refined.

When using lmfit, you absolutely must provide realistic initial values for all parameters to be optimized.  There are no circumstances under which this can be neglected.  If you are remotely unsure if your initial values are reasonable, plot the data and the model with the initial parameter values *before* trying a fit.  When doing a fit, you are asserting that you know the initial values are reasonable values for approximating your data.

A corollary: it is not a mistake of the algorithms or library that it fails to find a good solution when you give it unreasonable initial values.  This should be expected.

After a fit, always print out and read the fit report.  This contains the principle result.  A plot of the resulting fit can be useful -- a picture is worth a thousand words, as they say.  But the fit results contain the table of the fit results, and a table of numbers is worth a thousand pictures.  Let me repeat: ALWAYS PRINT OUT AND ACTUALLY READ THE FIT REPORT.  Do not post questions about the results of lmfit where this report is not included.